# Prevent iOS upgrade

Tags: ios, proxy

I want to prevent iOS upgrade on my device(s). In order to do that, I created one PAC proxy file and applied that Automatic Proxy configuration in Wi-Fi settings. But the iOS device is still able to download the upgrade. Please help me where am I wrong here? The PAC proxy is as seen in below link:

```
https://ad1.securearena.org/proxy.pac
```

In this proxy file, I tried to block the

- mesu.apple.com,

and

- appldnld.apple.com

DNS.

What am I missing here? How do I make sure iOS upgrade doesn't get downloaded?

Comment: Have you deleted the existing download of iOS update?

Comment: This is a [huge X - Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please fix.

Comment: Yes I have already deleted the downloaded update